# unable to conifgure NGINX of a vaadin application deployed in Wildfly using Keycloak authentification

Tags: nginx, wildfly, vaadin, keycloak

I am searching for days how to configure nginx to work with my application but it is nearly impossible.

**what I would like to do**

run my application using nginx (v=1.14) as a reverse proxy. My application is a web app written in vaadin (v=7.6.0) and deployed using a Wildfly (v=10). We use keycloak for the authentication (v=4.5.0).

**The Problem**

when I go to the url of my application, I am redirected to keycloak for the authentication. Then I can authentified and arrive on my webpage, but then I got this error message as a banner:

*https://xxx/webuploader/VAADIN/vaadinPush.js?=v=7.6.0 could not be loaded. Push will not work*

Indeed, I do not find the vaadinPush.js in the source of the web page (while I can find the vaadinBootstrap.js). But if I copy the url and authentified, I got the javascript from vaadin.

**what I think is the cause**
I think that something is not well configured between keycloak and nginx leading to a problem of authentication when the application is trying to get the vaadinPush.js.

another possibility is that the vaadinPush.js is not even asked (no trace of it in the console (like 403/404/500 ...)

**configuration**

*nginx.conf*

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    server_name uploader.xxx.be; 

    listen 443; # HTTPS listening port

        # SSL Certificates for Uploader.hospital.com
        ssl_certificate           ../conf/XXX.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key      ../conf/XXX.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;       

        location / {



            proxy_pass  http://*hostname*:*port*/webuploader/; 


            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme; 
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port 443; # must match listen port

            proxy_cookie_path /webuploader/ /;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        }

        location /webuploader/ {


            proxy_pass  http://*hostname*:*port*/webuploader/;  

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'sameorigin';

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port 443;

        }


        location /webuploader/webuploader/ {


            proxy_pass  http://*hostname*:*port*/webuploader/; 

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'sameorigin';

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port 443;



        }

         location /webuploader/PUSH {
             proxy_pass http://*hostname*:*port*/webuploader/PUSH;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
            proxy_read_timeout 84600s;
            proxy_send_timeout 84600s;
            break;
         }

    }

    server {
          # Configuration for Keycloak

        server_name auth.XXX.be; #Keycloak External URL 

        listen 443; # HTTPS listening port

        # SSL Certificates for auth.hospital.com
        ssl_certificate           ../conf/XXX.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key      ../conf/XXX.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;           

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://10.32.1.157:8081/; #Keycloak internal URL 

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'sameorigin';

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port 443; # must match listen port

            proxy_cookie_path / /;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
    }

         location /webuploader/PUSH {
             proxy_pass http://*hostname*:*port*/webuploader/PUSH;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
            proxy_read_timeout 84600s;
            proxy_send_timeout 84600s;
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

*standalone.xml of Keycloak*

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" enable-http2="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="https" />
```

*standalone.xml of Wildfly*

```
<realm name="XXX">
            <auth-server-url>https://auth.XXX.be/auth/</auth-server-url>
            <ssl-required>external</ssl-required>
</realm>


<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" enable-http2="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="https" />
```

*configuration of my application in Keycloak*

[Keycloak Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9NQZ.png)

thanks a lot in advance to all of you :)

Comment: I found a part of my problem. I added a @Javascript to import the vaadinPush.js. But the application ask me to log in every time I touch on an element of the page. 

Keycloak problem?